# Is this question well-formed? Let $T\in\mathcal B(X,Y),\ \lVert T\rVert<1,\ Y$ Banach, show $\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n\in\mathcal B(X,Y)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

If $X=Y$, then I think I have solved this problem entirely already. But if $X\neq Y$, then I don't understand what is being asked. How is $T^n$ defined when $X\neq Y$? When I consider $X=Y$, then I take (e.g.) $T^2(x)$ to be $T(T(x))$. Is that incorrect?

Comment: If $X\neq Y$ (or, to be generous, if $Y\not\subseteq X$...) and $T:X\to Y$, then $T^2$ makes no sense.

Comment: Right, thanks. So it seems that the question as given to us is not well-formed, unless we add the assumption that $Y\subseteq X$.

Comment: note that with $T : X \to X$, then when it converges (i.e. when $\|T\| < 1$) : $\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n = (I-T)^{-1}$